# linux/solaris + how to verify OS (linux / solaris ) creation date

Tags: linux, filesystems, solaris, shell-scripting

Please advice – how to verify OS (linux / solaris ) installation creation date

which file/packages/other – can be good indication when the operation system was created/installed ?

For example

I installed the linux 5.5 in date 23/10/2012 , How to verify in my linux this date ?
( the same question  about solaris 10 )

Comment: do you mean RedHat Enterprise Linux 5.5 ?

Comment: yes - but my question should be relevant for   all Linux versions ( from 5.0 until latest version )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best 2 solutions:

1. Look at your root file system creation. For ext2 and ext3 you should use

   dumpe2fs /dev/sdX1 | grep "Filesystem created:"

If you use XFS on solaris you should follow the same approach (probably xfs_db ?)

2. Find the installer log. there you will find files what are write in the moment of installation. In ubuntu for example I have /var/log/installer/lsb-release and the date of this file shows me the date of system installation.

Solution 1 is the absolute solution.

https://superuser.com/questions/402550/how-do-i-view-the-os-installation-date-on-linux

Answer (score 0):

try with long listing of /bin /sbin   files. check the dates of binaries there, you will get a hint.

I think in Solaris  /bin is a link to /usr/bin

anyways listing dates of binaries can turn out to be useful.

Comment: I need absolute solution so I will add the rule in my shell script